# org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: is not mapped

Tags: spring, entity-framework, hibernate, jpa

I am using hibernate 4.x with spring 4.x. I am unable to retrieve entities from the database. It is saying the entity is not mapped.

stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Person is not mapped [select p from Person p]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1750)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1683)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:331)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:293)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy106.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    at com.limeroad.services.hello.hibernate.PersonDao.selectAll(PersonDao.java:36)
    at com.limeroad.services.hello.hibernate.PersonDao$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$6ea17c1.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:717)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653)
    at com.limeroad.services.hello.hibernate.PersonDao$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d54888ad.selectAll(<generated>)
    at com.limeroad.services.hello.hibernate.PersonService.fetchAllPersons(PersonService.java:31)
    at com.limeroad.services.hello.hibernate.PersonService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$f158ab64.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:649)
    at com.limeroad.services.hello.hibernate.PersonService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$da9402f0.fetchAllPersons(<generated>)
    at com.limeroad.services.hello.hibernate.PersonController.initiatePasswordRecovery(PersonController.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1480)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1411)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1360)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1350)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:538)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:716)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:652)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:445)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:556)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:227)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1044)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:189)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:978)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:367)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:486)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:937)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:998)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:861)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:628)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Person is not mapped [select p from Person p]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.generateQueryException(QuerySyntaxException.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.QueryException.wrapWithQueryString(QueryException.java:120)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:158)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:190)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1800)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:328)
    ... 68 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Person is not mapped
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.requireClassPersister(SessionFactoryHelper.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementFactory.addFromElement(FromElementFactory.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromClause.addFromElement(FromClause.java:95)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:331)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3633)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3522)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:706)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:562)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:299)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:247)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:206)
    ... 76 more
```

dbContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.limeroad.services.*.dao.*" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url"
            value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/orderDB?autoReconnect=true" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="root" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

PersonDao.java

```
package com.limeroad.services.hello.hibernate;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.Query;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Repository("personDao")
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public class PersonDao {

  private static final String SELECT_QUERY = "select p from Person p";

  @PersistenceContext
  private EntityManager entityManager;

  public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return entityManager;
  }

  public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
    this.entityManager = entityManager;
  }

  public void insert(Person person) {
    entityManager.persist(person);
  }

  public List<Person> selectAll() {
    Query query = entityManager.createQuery(SELECT_QUERY);
    List<Person> persons = (List<Person>) query.getResultList();
    return persons;
  }

}
```

person.java

```
package com.limeroad.services.hello.hibernate;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;


@Table(name = "person")
@javax.persistence.Entity
@XmlRootElement(name = "person")
public class Person {
  private Integer id;
  private String name;
  private String email;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  @Column(name = "ID")
  public Integer getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String getEmail() {
    return email;
  }

  public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "Person [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", email=" + email + "]";
  }

}
```

There are lot of posts on stackoverflow in which addressing the same issue. But I was unable to find a definite solution for this.

Please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The value of `<property name="packagesToScan" value="com.limeroad.services.*.dao.*" />` should be the packages where your entities are in. So in your case it should be

```
<property name="packagesToScan" value="com.limeroad.services.hello.hibernate" />
```

Otherwise the entity scanning mechanism won't find your entity.